# Advance Custom fields keep returning the same value

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

So to elaborate, I have 11 posts and in each of those posts I input an image into advance custom fields form. But when I call them I get back 11 results but from just 1 post.

Here is what I'm working with. Just to tell you this is in functiuons.php since I want to get this as a shortcode so I can use it on multiple post types.

```
            function get_slider() {
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'projekti',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    );
                    $posts = get_posts($args);

                    ob_start();

                    if( $posts ): ?>
                    <div class="slider_slick">
                    <?php foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                        <?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
                            <?php while( have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
                                <?php // vars
                                $image = get_sub_field('image_slider');
                                $link = get_sub_field('slider_link');                       
                                ?>      
                                <div class="slide">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>                         
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;
                    return ob_get_clean();
        }
    add_shortcode ('slick_slider' , 'get_slider');
```

I have almost identical code on the template I created, but that one works, this one does not and I don't know why.

Comment: try using `WP_QUERY` instead `get_posts`

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work as well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: do you have rows of `slider` ? please add the output of `get_fields(get_the_ID());`  after the line `setup_postdata($post);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add

```
  global $post;
```

to the top of my function for it to work. Thanks for your help anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

Pass id of current post for the acf `have_rows()` function. I have done that using , `$currentId = get_the_ID();` and then using the variable $currentId where I need.

```
        function get_slider() {
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projekti',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                );
                $posts = get_posts($args);

                ob_start();

                if( $posts ): ?>
                <div class="slider_slick">
                <?php foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata( $post );
                 $currentId = get_the_ID();
                  ?>
                    <?php if( have_rows('slider', $currentId) ): ?>
                        <?php while( have_rows('slider', $currentId) ): the_row(); ?>
                            <?php // vars
                            $image = get_sub_field('image_slider');
                            $link = get_sub_field('slider_link');                       
                            ?>      
                            <div class="slide">
                                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>                         
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif;
                return ob_get_clean();
    }
add_shortcode ('slick_slider' , 'get_slider');
```